# How to temporarily straighten very thick and curly hair?

Tags: hair

My 5 year old daughters hair is very thick and very curly. I am well aware of proper hair care, protective braids and curls.

Sometimes she wants it straight. I've encouraged her to embrace her natural beauty (I wish I had her curls!). However she is 5 and very smart.

I want to know if there is a way I can temporarily straighten her hair and without it poofing outward without ruining her natural curls?

She has very small twists type curls and no straight hair anywhere. I don't want to hurt her hair by chemicals or perms or semi perms. If there's a way I'd love to know it! Just to make her day every now and then and give her that pep in her step.

Comment: Have you tried a flat iron? (The eventual poofing outward is going to be inevitable, though.)

Comment: Her hair is thick and course and it damages her hair. It has a natural frizz that is untamable lol

Answer (score 4):

Shampoo with keratin will aid with straightening using a flat iron, but I don't recommend it. Getting a professional blow out is her best bet.  I'm biracial and   occasionally want a temporary change. I feel her pain. It is also possible to use large rollers and relax the curls a lot which is satisfying. There is a web community dedicated to us natural curly peeps.  Knowing her curl type  (sounds like a 4b) will also help.  It's all about products. Curl creme!!! Tame the frizz using the LOC method, and make sure you use sulfate free shampoo.  Get her a silk pillow case, It's vital to fighting frizz. And start searching for a stylist who knows curls now. I drive 4hrs for my 2-3 trims a year. If they have never dry cut curls, run away!!!  Good luck and post a pic.  My babies both have red curls.  My son has a baby fro. Lol

Answer (score 3):

I'd use an [electric hair straightening brush for kids](http://hairbrushguides.com/for-kids/). This will give the possibility for her to have straightened hair without damaging her natural locks. This electric hair straightening tools make straightening quick and easy while treating the hair kindly. I use one myself and absolutely love it and I also straighten my daughter's hair for her from time to time too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for Argan Oil. It wont straighten her hair, but it will weigh it down and tame it so to speak. Gives hair a wet look. Shampoos and conditioners with Argan Oil never really worked for me. Other than that only a flat iron will do. The flat iron didn't do anything bad to my hair, just takes 2 hours to do. Male with 3ft long naturally very curly and very untamable hair.